# Why I get "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden" in SvelteKit?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sveltekit

I have a frontend project on SvelteKit with node adapter and backend API on Python with FastAPI. I conteinerized them, created services in docker-compose file and deployed on cloud service.

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"

  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
```

But when I send request to API with URL `http://server:8200/...` from SvelteKit form action I get exception `Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden`.

Why am I getting it?

Tried to add `ORIGIN` in `start` command with public cloud service virtual machine IP address and everything worked. But it looks like this is not a correct solution because public IP can be changed. I tried to use `http://server:8200`, `http://localhost:8200` and `http://0.0.0.0:8200` but it still didn't work.

```
"start": "export PORT=8100 && ORIGIN=... node ./build"
```

Could you explain what I am missing from [documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables)?

Answer (score 1):

The `ORIGIN` environment variable needs to be set the origin where the SvelteKit app is being served. From the [docs](https://HTTP%20doesn%27t%20give%20SvelteKit%20a%20reliable%20way%20to%20know%20the%20URL%20that%20is%20currently%20being%20requested.%20The%20simplest%20way%20to%20tell%20SvelteKit%20where%20the%20app%20is%20being%20served%20is%20to%20set%20the%20ORIGIN%20environment%20variable:):

> HTTP doesn't give SvelteKit a reliable way to know the URL that is currently being requested. The simplest way to tell SvelteKit where the app is being served is to set the ORIGIN environment variable:

Therefore, it must either be the public IP address of the server or a domain/subdomain that resolves to the public IP address of the server - your first attempt at a solution was correct. You need to get a static IP or host the client app somewhere else that lets you use a different adaptor.